How to get WooCommerce orders created from a given start date?
I need to get orders only if order was created from given date, let's say: 01/11/2024.
Then I would get order created from the day 01/11/2024 to the actual date (today).
I found this code which does something similar fetching orders within the last 24h only. I guess I need to convert my date to timestamp like:
$myDate = '2024/11/01';
$timestamp = strtotime($myDate);

But I can not figure out how to integrate/modify:
$order = wc_get_order( $customer_order );          
        
$date_created_dt = $order->get_date_completed();            
        
$timezone        = $date_created_dt->getTimezone(); // Get the timezone
$date_created_ts = $date_created_dt->getTimestamp(); // Get the timestamp in seconds

$now_dt = new WC_DateTime(); // Get current WC_DateTime object instance
$now_dt->setTimezone( $timezone ); // Set the same time zone
$now_ts = $now_dt->getTimestamp(); // Get the current timestamp in seconds

$twenty_four_hours = 24 * 60 * 60; // 24hours in seconds

$diff_in_seconds = $now_ts - $date_created_ts; // Get the difference (in seconds)

// Output
if ( $diff_in_seconds < $twenty_four_hours ) {
    echo '<p>Order created LESS than 24 hours ago</p>';
} 
        
        


Your question is not really clear. Are you trying to filter each order created from a given start date? Or you want to get WooCommerce all orders created from a given start date? Also, you should always give the credit to the code you picked, by adding a link in your question (please).

To get all orders starting from a given date, you can use a query compatible with High-Performance Order Storage (HPOS) using wc_get_orders() function with date_created argument as follows:
$start_date = '2024/11/01';

$start_date_obj = new WC_DateTime($start_date); // Get the WC_DateTime object 
$start_date_obj->setTimezone( wp_timezone() ); // Set WordPress timezone

// Query all orders starting from the defined date
$orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'limit'         => -1,
    'date_created'  => '>=' . $start_date_obj->date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ), 
) );

// Loop through orders starting from the given date
foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    // Do something
}

For the timezone:  Using WordPress wp_timezone() is much more simpler.
Other useful WC_Order_Query arguments:
The order statuses to query using 'status'.
The user ID to target using 'customer'.
The date type: 'date_created', 'date_modified', 'date_completed' or 'date_paid'.
See wc_get_orders and WC_Order_Query developer documentation
To filter an order from a given start date, we start using a similar code:
$start_date = '2024/11/01';

$start_date_obj   = new WC_DateTime($start_date); // Get the WC_DateTime object 
$start_date_obj->setTimezone( wp_timezone() ); // Set WordPress timezone

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );  // Get the WC_Order object form the ID

$order_date = $order->get_date_created(); // Get order creation date object

// Dates timestamp comparison 
if ( $order_date->getTimestamp() >= $start_date_obj->getTimestamp() ) {
    // Output something
    printf( '<p>Order created after %s start date.</p>', $start_date );
} 

See WC_DateTime Class and methods and native PHP DateTime Class and methods.

To retrieve orders created from a specific date (like 01/11/2024) up to today, you can modify the code to compare order dates with a set starting date instead of just the past 24 hours.
$customer_order_id = 123; // Replace with the actual order ID
$order = wc_get_order($customer_order_id);

if ($order) {
    // Define the start date
    $start_date = '2024-11-01'; // Start date in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format
    $start_dt = new WC_DateTime($start_date); // Convert start date to WC_DateTime object
    $start_ts = $start_dt->getTimestamp(); // Get timestamp of start date

    // Get order creation date and convert to timestamp
    $date_created_dt = $order->get_date_created();
    $order_created_ts = $date_created_dt->getTimestamp(); 

    // Compare timestamps
    if ($order_created_ts >= $start_ts) {
        echo '<p>Order created on or after ' . $start_date . '</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Order was created before ' . $start_date . '</p>';
    }
}

